# Weird sound coming from Asus UX391UA

Tags: hardware-failure, clicking-sound

Just got an Asus UX391UA. The laptop works like a charm, but I am a little worried about the sound coming from the computer. So I wonder if any of you can identify the sound.

The sound is quite low and discrete and it sound almost like the sound a mechanical hard drive makes when it writes or reads from disk. But the laptop has an M.2 SSD.

You can listen to it here: https://soundcloud.com/user-341947109/ux391ua-sound

Should I be worried that the sound might be indicating that something is wrong with the computer?

Comment: Not sure this is an answerable question, since it is probably exclusive to your machine.  I had an issue when my last laptop was new where there was a thin piece of plastic that was loose in the fan housing, causing it to make weird clicking noises on occasion.  Could it be something like that?

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with moving parts. It sound more like voltage spikes or perhaps just the sound from the CPU itself. I would avoid opening the laptop so to keep the warranty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the laptop swapped for a new one. It turns out that they both make this sound. The new one I got seems like a "refurbished" one, but it works flawlessly.  Although the clicking sound is somewhat reduced on the new one I might just be super sensitive about it, now that I first noticed it. I still do not know what is actually causing the sound, but since it is merely impossible to investigate this without opening the laptop I will make this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something is wrong with such a sound being made by a computer with only an
SSD disk.
Not necessarily a serious problem, but it requires checking.

Checks :

- If any application is using the speaker
- Disconnect all possible devices
- Boot in Safe Mode
- Verify all moving parts such as the CD (if any) and fans.

Comment: The specs of the model indicates that there should be no components with moving parts. Will try safe mode though but I doubt it will help.

Comment: It does have fan(s) .